# Using LOAD DATA INFILE on a list of items (multilevel parent/children)?

Tags: mysql, import, load-data-infile

I have a textfile of Quickbooks items (multilevel parent/children) that need to be loaded into a MySQL database on a regular basis.  I wanted to use something similar to LOAD DATA INFILE vs looping through the list and adding each individually.  A list example follows:

Cables
Cables:USB
Cables:USB:6feet
Networking
Networking:Routers
Networking:Routers:DLink

In MySQL, I need to separate the items so that they point to their parent item (using a field such as int parentid).  I can process/format the data before dumping it to the INFILE, however I do not know how to maintain the hierarchy during import.  Is LOAD DATA INFILE the best approach?

Comment: no. load data infile cannot handle this. it's for single-level **FLAT** data structures. e.g. basically .csv files. you'll have to do this client-side

Comment: Okay, it should be less than 300 items vs 1000s. If there are no other approaches then I will loop through the items and add them individually.  I was hoping to find a more efficient way than running 300 queries, but I guess that's how the job gets done:). Ty.